# J2ME Telecom Operator code, need help in smsConnection, and HTTP connection setup

Tags: windows

```
String smsConnection = "sms://:" + "21000";`
```

How can we implement custom fonts, in J2ME, Please could you write a code snippet and post it for me. Thanx and Regards, Laxman Mittal

Answer (score 0):

Hi We can use bitmapfont in j2me,

First Create the bitmap font your own using [bitmap font creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitmapfont/).

Then you need to add the BitmapFont class to your project,

```
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
 import net.sergetk.mobile.lcdui.BitmapFont;


public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {
    BitmapFont myFont;

    public MyCanvas() {
        myFont = new BitmapFont("myfont.fnt");
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(0x00FF00); // green
        myFont.drawString(g, "Hello, world!", 0, 0, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey sivakg2000, first of all thanks for making an effort to reply to my post. The one that u sent is only for English. I need to implement the same for THAI fonts and CHINESE fonts